# Understanding Angular2 change event

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular2 , and working on sample to learn the concepts

Below is my partial sample code ,

```
...
....
<select name="mExp" [(ngModel)]="model.exp"    (change)="expChange($event.target.value)">
 <option *ngFor="let exp of modelExps" [value]="exp.Name">{{exp.Value}}   </option>
</select>
...
...

....
....
expChange(newExp: string) {
  this.model.exp = newExp;
  console.log(this.model);
}
...
....
```

In brief , when user selects an option in the dropdown , the selected value
is assigned to "this.model.exp" , what if i need to cancel the assignment
based on a certain value for "newExp".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the binding

```
<select name="mExp" [ngModel]="model.exp" (ngModelChange)="$event === 3 ? expChange($event) : null">
```

Using `ngModelChange` is usually better because there are timing differences when `change` (`<select>` native event) and `ngModelChange` are emitted which can cause issues when used together with `ngModel`.