# Select Option: Angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to prevent or continue with the option that is currently being selected based on a flag:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedStudent" (change)="onSelectChange($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let student of list" [ngValue]="student">{{student.name}}</option>
    </select>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private list: Object = [
    {name: 'Abc', age: '24'},
    {name: 'Def', age: '25'},
    {name: 'Ghi', age: '25'},
    {name: 'Jkl', age: '25'},
    {name: 'Mno', age: '25'}
  ];
  private selectedStudent: Object;

  private condition: boolean = true;

  onSelectChange(event) {
    if (this.condition) {
      // select the option being selected
    } else {
      // prevent any change in option
    }
  }
}
```

How to achieve the desired effect.
Moreover, if I use [ngValue], initially nothing is shown in the select option dropdown. Why so?

Comment: you need for `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: I tried using event.preventDefault() but this does not prevent dropdown to change.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to hopefully point you in the right direction.

`[ngValue]` should be `[value]`

`this.condition` is always true.  You're not binding it to anything to change it's value so not sure what it's purpose is.

You can split the binding using `(ngModelChange)` instead of the `(change)` event.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39139053/5782634) has a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedStudent" (ngModelChange)="onSelectChange($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let student of list" [ngValue]="student" [disabled]='student.flag'>{{student.name}}</option>
    </select>

  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private list: Object = [
    {name: 'Abc', age: '24',flag: true},
    {name: 'Def', age: '25',flag: false},
    {name: 'Ghi', age: '25',flag: false},
    {name: 'Jkl', age: '25',flag: true},
    {name: 'Mno', age: '25',flag: true}
  ];
```